# Getting error when removing the defalt apiAuthentication handler and adding myCustomhandler, any idea?

Tags: handler, wso2-api-manager, wso2

(previously it was working fine but don't what is changed )
When i am removing the default handler from synapse configs and adding my custom handler it is giving this error

```
[2022-01-13 10:44:41,924] ERROR - ServerWorker Error processing POST request for : /dev/21.2/ext-rt/publish/TestTenant/SmooksProviderTranslation.csv.

java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.doRoleBasedAccessThrottlingWithCEP_aroundBody0(ThrottleHandler.java:193) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.doRoleBasedAccessThrottlingWithCEP(ThrottleHandler.java:145) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.doThrottle_aroundBody12(ThrottleHandler.java:585) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.doThrottle(ThrottleHandler.java:562) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.handleRequest_aroundBody8(ThrottleHandler.java:522) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.ThrottleHandler.handleRequest(ThrottleHandler.java:503) ~[org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway_6.7.206.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:373) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:2.1.7-wso2v183]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.apiProcessNonDefaultStrategy(RESTRequestHandler.java:144) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:2.1.7-wso2v183]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.identifyAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:164) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:2.1.7-wso2v183]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:95) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:2.1.7-wso2v183]
        at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:73) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:2.1.7-wso2v183]
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:331) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:2.1.7-wso2v183]
        at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:99) ~[synapse-core_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:2.1.7-wso2v183]
        at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180) ~[axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:367) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:426) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:?]
        at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:181) [synapse-nhttp-transport_2.1.7.wso2v183.jar:?]
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172) [axis2_1.6.1.wso2v41.jar:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128) [?:?]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628) [?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) [?:?]
```

Below is the authenticate() method from myCustomHandler.java class, which has the AuthenticationContext object

```
    public boolean authenticate(MessageContext synCtx) throws APISecurityException {
    Map headers = getTransportHeaders(synCtx);
    String authHeader = getAuthorizationHeader(headers);
    String postmanToken = getPostmanToken(headers);

    String clientIP = "10.110.67.195";

    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext axis2MessageContext = ((Axis2MessageContext) synCtx)
            .getAxis2MessageContext();
    AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext();
    authContext.setAuthenticated(true);

    // Can modify to support scopes based throttle policy selection
    authContext.setTier(APIConstants.UNLIMITED_TIER);
    authContext.setStopOnQuotaReach(true);
    authContext.setApiKey(clientIP);
    authContext.setKeyType(APIConstants.API_KEY_TYPE_PRODUCTION);
    authContext.setUsername((String) axis2MessageContext.getProperty("user"));
    authContext.setCallerToken(null);
    authContext.setApplicationName(null);
    authContext.setApplicationId(clientIP);
    authContext.setConsumerKey(null);
    log.debug("**** applicationID is --- " + authContext.getApplicationId());
    APISecurityUtils.setAuthenticationContext(synCtx, authContext, null);

    System.out.println("**** TE is HERE");
    log.debug("**** TE is HERE2");
    log.debug("**** Header is --- " + headers);
    log.debug("**** AuthHeader is --- " + authHeader);
    log.debug("**** Postman token  is --- " + postmanToken);

    return true;
    /*
     * if (authHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) { return true; } return false;
     */
}
```

Comment: What is the APIM version? APIM 3.2.0?

Comment: Yes wso2 apim 3.2.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is with the AuthenticationContext object. We populate the authContext object at the Authentication handler(in each authenticator [1]) and this object is used at the throttle handler[2]. when you replaced the Authentication handler with your custom handler, you might have missed populating this object. Try populating this object as [1].

[1] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.7.206/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/security/oauth/OAuthAuthenticator.java#L301
[2] - https://github.com/wso2/carbon-apimgt/blob/v6.7.206/components/apimgt/org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/apimgt/gateway/handlers/throttling/ThrottleHandler.java#L193

Comment: Thanks Akshitha, thanks for your reply. Why they have not mentioned this in their official document ? The code there looks so simple this is the link please share your valuable thought I am stuck at this point from long time ...
https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/3.2.0/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/

Comment: can you please help ?

Comment: This is a bug that we have to fix. In the throttle handler, authcontext object is null and we need to retrieve the applicaitonId it after checking for nullity. Can you populate the authenticationContext Object as we are doing in the OAuthAuthenticator and set the object the message context? This will fix the NPE.

Comment: I have populated the authenticationContext Object and set some context but still showing NPE. I have also print the application id in my customHandler it is not null ... then why ThrottleHandler class is not able to retrieve this object ?(I have edited the question with the code snippet can you just go through and check if it right ?)

Comment: The problem was with username that was coming null and I was setting this to authcontext. Thanks for help !!